# Is there any way to edit my bash color theme partially?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, themes

I created my custom bash color theme on some web site few months before.
However, I just want to edit some color in my bash theme now.
But it's hard to understand what they mean in screenshot below.

[image]

What i'm curious about is if there is some way to edit my bash color for
some part.

+This is my first time to post question here, so I'm afraid that I did a bad question. If i did, please tell me problems. Thank you so much.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're not familiar with how terminal colors work, I'd highly suggest reading [this article](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting), or just searching the web for **ANSI/VT100 color codes**.

Having said that, let's look at a part of the code from your snippet. (Also, in future, please remember to actually copy and paste the code in a code block so that it becomes easier for us to edit/debug/copy-paste.

The term `LS_COLORS` suggests that it colorizes the output of the `ls` command based on a custom criterion. Further inspection reveals that it assigns a certain "style" to each file type noted.

So, for example, `*.zip` (i.e., all zip files) get styled to `01;31`. Now refer to the article above. The attributes are seperated by a `;` and they're in the order "styling;foreground_color;background_color". So, in your case, I'm guessing the background color isn't included. So, first part, `01` sets the text formatting to bold, and `31` sets the text color to red.

Just edit the colors in that statement as you'd like followed by saving the file, and you should see the changes after restarting the terminal.

Comment: Would you mind telling me what is 'PS1' in .bashrc? I just found that my .bashrc file has lines starting with 'PS1' and 'export' and when i commentize it, then my bash theme is changed

Comment: @davidHwang PS1 or "Prompt Screen 1" is just one of the prompts available for your user. There are more (PS2, PS3, etc.) and they just show you your username, your hostname and present directory (of course you could add more information). Check out this article for help: http://www.linuxnix.com/linuxunix-shell-ps1-prompt-explained-in-detail.

A typical PS1 looks like : `[root@linuxnix dev]#`.

Answer (score 0):

## `$LS_COLORS` is actualy *ls* theme, not *bash* theme.

It is a colon separated list of rules in format `key=pattern` where key is

```
no    NORMAL, NORM            Global default, although everything should be something
fi    FILE                    Normal file
di    DIR                     Directory
ln    SYMLINK, LINK, LNK      Symbolic link. If you set this to ‘target’ instead of a numerical value, the color is as for the file pointed to.
pi    FIFO, PIPE              Named pipe
do    DOOR                    Door
bd    BLOCK, BLK              Block device
cd    CHAR, CHR               Character device
or    ORPHAN                  Symbolic link pointing to a non-existent file
so    SOCK                    Socket
su    SETUID                  File that is setuid (u+s)
sg    SETGID                  File that is setgid (g+s)
tw    STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE   Directory that is sticky and other-writable (+t,o+w)
ow    OTHER_WRITABLE          Directory that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
st    STICKY                  Directory with the sticky bit set (+t) and not other-writable
ex    EXEC                    Executable file (i.e. has ‘x’ set in permissions)
mi    MISSING                 Non-existent file pointed to by a symbolic link (visible when you type ls -l)
lc    LEFTCODE, LEFT          Opening terminal code
rc    RIGHTCODE, RIGHT        Closing terminal code
ec    ENDCODE, END            Non-filename text
*.extension                   Every file using this extension e.g. *.jpg
```

and pattern is a semicolon separated list of effects and colors

### Effects

```
00  Default colour
01  Bold
04  Underlined
05  Flashing text
07  Reversetd
08  Concealed
```

### Colours

```
30  Black
31  Red
32  Green
33  Orange
34  Blue
35  Purple
36  Cyan
37  Grey
```

### Backgrounds

```
40  Black background
41  Red background
42  Green background
43  Orange background
44  Blue background
45  Purple background
46  Cyan background
47  Grey background
```

### Extra colours

```
90  Dark grey
91  Light red
92  Light green
93  Yellow
94  Light blue
95  Light purple
96  Turquoise
97  White
100 Dark grey background
101 Light red background
102 Light green background
103 Yellow background
104 Light blue background
105 Light purple background
106 Turquoise background
```

[Configuring LS_COLORS](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors)